# Slot in the code

Tags: plotting, slot

I am given the following code in my notes:

```
  Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Plot of Sin[x y]",  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#] &)]
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Plot of Sin[x y]",  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#1] &)]
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Plot of Sin[x y]",  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#2] &)]
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Plot of Sin[x y]",  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#3] &)]
```

I dont understand what the # values in the above context is. What values are being put in each case in the above code.

In general context the hash is called a slot and it is where the values are plugged in to the function

Comment: Yes... and the values passed to the `ColorFunction` are (internally) the value of the point being plotted.  For functions such as `Plot3D`, the values are two-dimensional vectors, so #1 and #2 are the coordinates.

Comment: And, so is `#3`.

Answer (score 2):

Always good to play around and see what things actually do.

Simplifying your code to highlight the `GrayLevel` / `Slot` question:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3},ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#] &)]
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3},ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#1] &)]
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3},ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#2] &)]
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3},ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#3] &)]
```

Which gives:

[image]

A little further investigation:

```
(GrayLevel[#] &) == (GrayLevel[#1] &)
True
```

So it doesn't look like you need both.

In the case of `Plot3D`, `ColorFunction` applies a color or in your cases, variation of gray to differences in the specified co-ordinates of the surface of the plot.

So, it looks like,

`#` or `#1` applies it to the x axis, `#2` to the y axis and `#3` to the z axis.